# Finding subgroups of the Real Numbers

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, infinite-groups

Find a subgroup of $\left (\mathbb R -\{0\}, \times\right)$ with a finite number of elements, which is not just the trivial subgroup $\{1\}$.

Find a subgroup of $\left(\mathbb R − \{0\}, \times\right)$ with an infinite number of elements, which is not just  $\mathbb R − \{0\}$ itself.

Is it possible to find a subgroup of $\left(\mathbb R, + \right)$ with a finite number of elements which is not just the trivial subgroup $\{0\}$?

I've been given these three questions for homework but I'm struggling quiet a bit with them. Thanks to anyone who is able to help.

Comment: What about $\{-1,1\}$?

Comment: For the second one, try the set of integer powers of $2$ (positive, negative or zero power). I mean the powers are integers, not necessarily the results, e.g. $2^{-3}=1/8$ would be in it.

Comment: It is not possible to find a nontrivial finite subgroup of $(R, +)$. Take an element $x \in R$, other than identity, and observe the repeated sums $x$, $2x$, $3x$, ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1)  {1,-1}.  Identity is 1, $-1^{-1}=-1$

Can prove it is the only one by considering if $b$ is in the group so are all infinite $b^n$.

2) let $b$ be any real number not equal to 1 or -1.  Then {$b^n$, *} is an infinite group.  1 is the identity and $b^n*b^m=b^{m+n} $.  $(b^n)^{-1}=b^{-n} $.

3) this can't be done.  If $b $ in the group then so is $b+b,b+b+b,4b,5b,...nb $ for any possible integer n.  This must be in infinite set.